# AnyChart Android does not work with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, anychart

I am trying to use anychart to plot data stored from firebase database but I cannot retrieve data with ValueDataEntry.
I have already tested the connection to my database using System.out.println() to retrieve data and it's fine.

```
public class statistics extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);

        AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

        Cartesian cartesian = AnyChart.column();
        final List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("sales");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Sales sales = ds.getValue(Sales.class);
                    data.add(new ValueDataEntry(sales.getName(), sales.getSold()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Column column = cartesian.column(data);

        column.tooltip()
                .titleFormat("{%X}")
                .position(Position.CENTER_BOTTOM)
                .anchor(Anchor.CENTER_BOTTOM)
                .offsetX(0d)
                .offsetY(5d)
                .format("${%Value}{groupsSeparator: }");

        cartesian.animation(true);
        cartesian.title("sample title");

        cartesian.yScale().minimum(0d);

        cartesian.yAxis(0).labels().format("${%Value}{groupsSeparator: }");

        cartesian.tooltip().positionMode(TooltipPositionMode.POINT);
        cartesian.interactivity().hoverMode(HoverMode.BY_X);

        cartesian.xAxis(0).title("Product");
        cartesian.yAxis(0).title("Revenue");

        anyChartView.setChart(cartesian);

    }
```

here is my class

```
public class Sales {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public int sold;
    public Sales() {
    }

    public Sales(String id, String name, int sold) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSold() {
        return sold;
    }

    public void setSold(int sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }
}
```

I just simply want to populate a bar graph with data from firebase.

Comment: Everyting looks normal, can you share your "Sales.Class" and did you try to print a data with log report at console. for example sales.getName... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log

Comment: I tried to print data with System.out.println and it worked but ValueDataEntry isn't taking any data, also tried to store data to an array first then add it to the chart with loop but it still doesn't work @mehmet

Comment: "stackoverflow said my post has too many codes so it's screenshot"  It's complaining that you haven't written enough information that's _not_ code.  Please also see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)

Comment: Please, can you provide the full chart configuration code? Also, check the content of the List after populating data in the loop.